# SortableJS keep non draggable items fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, dom-manipulation, sortablejs

I have a list created using SortableJS and has a few items which cannot be dragged and dropped. Here is an example of how it looks:

```
<ul id="user_selections">
    <li class="no_drag">Fixed</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li class="no_drag">Fixed</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="no_drag">Fixed</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li class="no_drag">Fixed</li>
</ul>
```

Class `no_drag` are the items that are fixed.

Now when I move Items 3 above Item 1 the structure should be like this:

```
<ul id="user_selections">
    <li class="no_drag">Fixed</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li class="no_drag">Fixed</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li class="no_drag">Fixed</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="no_drag">Fixed</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this kind of behaviour.

Here is the JS code I have tried:

```
var el = document.getElementById('user_selections');
if (el) {
    const sortable = Sortable.create(el, {
        filter: '.no_drag',
        onMove(evt, oe) {
            return evt.related.className.indexOf('no_drag') === -1;
        },
        preventOnFilter: false,
        onEnd: function(/**Event*/evt) {
            // Some ajax call to save the new indexes
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution that works perfectly for first and last elements.
Add this in options:

```
onMove: function(e) {
            if(e.related.classList.contains('no_drag')) {
                return false;
            }
        },
```

If drop target is something you don't want moved it will return false, i.e. it will be ignored as drop target.

Elements in the middle will also be ignored, but you can still target elements after (or before) them, so they will be moved.